# Is using Threading in Pygame good Idea to make the game faster?

Tags: python, pygame, python-multithreading

I recently made a few games with **Pygame** but I found out that it is quite slow and laggy also there isn't any bug in my game. I tried everything apart from creating multiple threads in my game but I am wondering if creating them could lead to some glitches or trouble in my game.

Comment: Pygame is intended for educational purposes only. It is completely CPU bound and does not use the GPU, so it is "slow". All the drawing and event handling must be done in the main thread (the thread in which the display window was created).

Comment: The other reason that new programmers say their programs are slow is because they use inappropriate algorithms. I should know because I used to use bubble sorts when I should have been using quicksort.

Comment: threads may run in different moments (system decide which treat has access to CPU) and sometimes it can make problem to synchronize data from different threads.

Comment: You should [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/582337/2280890) your program to see where bottlenecks lie. One Common error is loading images multiple times instead of just once.

Comment: Threading can be a tool to improve performance, but it's no magic bullet that will solve things automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, it could be used very sparsely and if you really know what you are doing. Threading is really not a beginner concept and threading + pygame is most likely a bad idea, will cause more problems than it solves.

So short answer is "no", don't use threading. If your games are laggy that probably comes from your programming skills. Perhaps you could create a new post with a more specific example, sharing some code of yours, I'm sure the community would give you tons of advise to improve your coding.

You can check out "DaFluffyPotato" on youtube. He is one of the best content creator when it comes to making complexe/advance games with pygame and pygame optimization.

Comment: Thanks @Anto your tips will help me a ton in my coding future!!